# Sistema simples de ganho de experiência em Python

Tags: python

estou com algumas dúvidas, estou criando um RPG por comandos, coisa simples pra por em prática o que estou aprendendo. A verdade é que eu travei em uma situação, quero criar um comando em que o Player escolhe a função "Caçar", a partir daí é gerado um numero aleatório (entre 1 e 100) que vai definir quanta XP ele ganhou na caçada, depois eu queria somar esse numero aleatório a Experiencia do player, somando cada vez que ele caçar, bom, eu consegui alguns resultados e vários problemas tambem:

```
    import random, time

level = 1
n_level = 50

exp_loot = random.randint(1,100)
exp = 0

while exp >= n_level:
    level += 1
    n_level = round(n_level * 2)

def separador():
    print('-' * 50)

def hunt():
    exp_loot = random.randint(1,100)
    return exp_loot

def stats():
    separador()
    print('Level: {}'.format(level))
    print('EXP: {}/{}'.format(exp, n_level))
    separador()


while True:
    player = int(input(''))

    if player == 0:
        print('Voce está caçando..')
        exp += hunt()
        time.sleep(1)
        print('Você ganhou {}xp'.format(hunt()))

    elif player == 1:
        stats()
```

Quando o Player digita o numero 1, mostra o status (Level e XP)
Quando digita o numero 0 ele caça

Porém a soma do xp aleatorio não está correta, alguem consegue me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que quando você mostra a quantidade de XP ganha na caça você chama o `hunt()` obtendo um novo valor. Você deve criar uma variável para guardar o valor ganho e depois somar o XP total do jogador com o XP ganho da caça. Veja como ficou o código abaixo:

```
import random, time

level = 1
n_level = 50

exp_loot = random.randint(1,100)
exp = 0

while exp >= n_level:
    level += 1
    n_level = round(n_level * 2)

def separador():
    print('-' * 50)

def hunt():
    exp_loot = random.randint(1,100)
    return exp_loot

def stats():
    global exp
    separador()
    print('Level: {}'.format(level))
    print('EXP: {}/{}'.format(exp, n_level))
    separador()


while True:
    player = int(input(''))

    if player == 0:
        print('Você está caçando...')

        # Obtém o XP ganho da caça
        exp_hunt = hunt()

        # Soma o XP total com o da caça
        exp += exp_hunt
        time.sleep(1)

        # Mostra o XP ganho da caça que está na variável "exp_hunt"
        print('Você ganhou {}xp'.format(exp_hunt))

    elif player == 1:
        stats()
```

Comment: Cara, era exatamente isso que eu precisava, você é um anjo, muito obrigado

Comment: Arigatou Gozaimasu <3